# CSS, dynamic length within an overflow scroll

Tags: css, overflow

I have a div, which appears a a vertical line down the middle of my page. It is set to height:"90%" and starts at a 5% top. The page is set to overflow:scroll. When I press some of the elements on my page, they expand and thus they I need to scroll more to see them. However, I would like the  vertical line down the middle to expand also such that it is 90% of the total scroll length, not just the window length.

Does anyone know how to do this?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post existing code that you have/ screenshot of what you are trying to achive.

Comment: You can find a screenshot here: https://ibb.co/ckDCYQs. In the screen shot, I have expanded a couple of the items, I need the length of the white line in the center to expand also when this happens. The height of the whit line is currently set to 90% in my CSS. This is 90% of the div size though, not the scroll length.

Comment: I got ur problem, can you please share code on jsfiddle so that I can help easily.